# Why use a package manager with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm currently evaluating C++ package managers for a project at work and am starting to wonder why do I need them when CMake and a remote DVCS server seem to do the trick just fine.

On my personal projects I use [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) to pull and build any dependencies I have. Meanwhile Conan, vcpkg, hunter and possibly others claim to do the same thing.

vcpkg for example seems to require each project to have a .cmake file so it can be used with CMake find_package.

So, why use a package manager at all?

Comment: "why use a package manager at all?" - For **reuse** packages in different projects. With `ExternalProject_Add` you duplicate compilation of 3d-party package for every project which uses it. Package manager allows to avoid duplicate compilation.

Comment: Package managers also provide binary packages.

Comment: @Tsyvarev but package managers like vcpkg work around source code, not binary packages right?

Comment: Hm, according to what I have read about vcpkg, with `vcpkg install XXX` it takes the source code of the package, and **builds** and **installs** it. So, futher users of command `find_package(XXX)` take a **binary** package, not a source one.

Comment: But so does CMake?

Comment: @ruipacheco no `ExternalProject_Add` does this once *per build folder*

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. All I needed to do was to import a library which is distributed via a number of header files. At first I was using Conan cmake, which was proving very difficult to both import and use the library. After seeing your question, I am now using [`FetchContent`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html), and I've even gone as far as to make it its own [cmake module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#find-modules), so that I can just do `find_package(name_of_package)`. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While using CMake's `ExternalProject_Add` directly can have advantages such as compile flags that match exactly, correctly configuring packages is not always trivial. Furthermore, package managers allow you to reuse dependency sources *and binaries* between projects, leading to massively reduced storage requirements. This is true even in package managers like vcpkg that build from source, as they only download sources once (and build once per configuration to generate binaries) and not once *per build folder* (and per configuration for binaries). And those savings can be significant, especially with dependencies like Qt that are several gigabytes in size. Analogously, you also save a lot of time.

TL;DR:

- Ease of use
- Reduced storage requirements (if you use a library more than once)
- Reduced build times (if the package manager has binary packages or you use a library more than once)

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple (independently built) projects, and they use a lot of the same libraries, a package manager like hunter or vcpkg will compile and store libraries only once (per build platform), saving build time and disk space.

But if your projects are built together, and you cross-compile for multiple platforms (Windows x86, Windows x64, macOS, Linux, iOS, Android (4 different ABIs), WebAssembly, etc.), you indeed may be better off using `FetchContent` or `ExternalProject` directly.

For me it was the second case ([Scapix](https://github.com/scapix-com/scapix) project), and in the end I created a small and very simple "package manager" ([cmodule](https://github.com/scapix-com/cmodule)) specifically for this case: it only shares downloaded and unpacked library sources, while builds are performed as part of the overall project build.